# How to load a resource bundle from a file resource in Java?

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I have a file called `mybundle.txt` in `c:/temp` -

`c:/temp/mybundle.txt`

How do I load this file into a `java.util.ResourceBundle`? The file is a valid resource bundle.

This does not seem to work:

```
java.net.URL resourceURL = null;

String path = "c:/temp/mybundle.txt";
java.io.File fl = new java.io.File(path);

try {
   resourceURL = fl.toURI().toURL();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {             
}           

URLClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(new java.net.URL[]{resourceURL});
java.util.ResourceBundle bundle = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle( path , 
                java.util.Locale.getDefault(), urlLoader );
```

Answer (score 79):

As long as you name your resource bundle files correctly (with a .properties extension), then this works:

```
File file = new File("C:\\temp");
URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myResource", Locale.getDefault(), loader);
```

where "c:\temp" is the external folder (NOT on the classpath) holding the property files, and "myResource" relates to myResource.properties, myResource_fr_FR.properties, etc.

Credit to http://www.coderanch.com/t/432762/java/java/absolute-path-bundle-file

Comment: But maybe this will reload the bundle every time?

Comment: Note: You should probably close the `URLClassLoader` otherwise the file is locked as long as your application runs.

Answer (score 51):

When you say it's "a valid resource bundle" - is it a property resource bundle? If so, the simplest way of loading it probably:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:/temp/mybundle.txt")) {
  return new PropertyResourceBundle(fis);
}
```

Comment: Hey Jon, doesn't this miss the localization issue that would be the main reason for using a bundle in the first place?

Comment: There's no indication that he's actually got more than one file. The fact that it's got a .txt suffix isn't terribly encouraging. But yes, it would fail in that situation.

Comment: Rather than loading a file manually (i.e. with `FileInputStream`) and constructing a `ProperyResourceBundle`, should't the "right way" be to use the `ResourceBundle.getBundle(...)` method?

Comment: @Vihung `ResourceBundle.getBundle()` will load a resource bundle from the classpath and using a given Locale. Not the "raw" file as the OP expects.

Answer (score 22):

1) Change the extension to properties (ex. mybundle.properties.)
2) Put your file into a jar and add it to your classpath.
3) Access the properties using this code:

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("mybundle");
String propertyValue = rb.getString("key");
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible if the jar is embedded in an executable file by Launch4j and such...

Comment: The property file doesn't have to be inside a JAR. If the class is in a package `a.b.c.MyClass.java`, then `mybundle.properties` has to be in the *parent* folder of `a`, which would be the classpath.
I.e. for a class `/myproject/a/b/c/MyClass.java` the resource bundle must be placed in `/myproject/mybundle.properties`.

Comment: I am using Maven. I put the file in the resource folder such as `src/test/resources` or `src/main/resources` and it worked. Then, I found out that it was copied to `target/test-classes` which actually matched your comment. I think this is because the folder `target/test-classes` is part of the classpath.

Answer (score 11):

From the JavaDocs for `ResourceBundle.getBundle(String baseName)`:

> `baseName` - the base name of the
>   resource bundle, a fully qualified
>   class name

What this means in plain English is that the resource bundle must be on the classpath and that `baseName` should be the package containing the bundle plus the bundle name, `mybundle` in your case.

Leave off the extension and any locale that forms part of the bundle name, the JVM will sort that for you according to default locale - see the docs on [java.util.ResourceBundle](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) for more info.

Answer (score 7):

For JSF Application

To get resource bundle prop files from a given file path to use them in a JSF app.

- Set the bundle with URLClassLoader for a class that extends
  ResourceBundle to load the bundle from the file path.
- Specify the class at `basename` property of `loadBundle` tag.
  `<f:loadBundle    basename="Message" var="msg" />`

For basic implementation of extended RB please see the sample at [Sample Customized Resource Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451215/jsf-how-to-remove-the-surrounding-if-message-not-found-in-messagebundle/6452047#6452047)

```
/* Create this class to make it base class for Loading Bundle for JSF apps */
public class Message extends ResourceBundle {
        public Messages (){
                File file = new File("D:\\properties\\i18n");  
                ClassLoader loader=null;
                   try {
                       URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};  
                       loader = new URLClassLoader(urls); 
                       ResourceBundle bundle = getBundle("message", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale(), loader);
                       setParent(bundle);
                       } catch (MalformedURLException ex) { }
       }
      .
      .
      .
    }
```

Otherwise, get the bundle from getBundle method but locale from others source like `Locale.getDefault()`, the new (RB)class may not require in this case.

Answer (score 5):

If, like me, you actually wanted to load .properties files from your filesystem instead of the classpath, but otherwise keep all the smarts related to lookup, then do the following:

1. Create a subclass of `java.util.ResourceBundle.Control`
2. Override the `newBundle()` method

In this silly example, I assume you have a folder at `C:\temp` which contains a flat list of ".properties" files:

```
public class MyControl extends Control {
@Override
public ResourceBundle newBundle(String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
        throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException {

    if (!format.equals("java.properties")) {
        return null;
    }

    String bundleName = toBundleName(baseName, locale);
    ResourceBundle bundle = null;

    // A simple loading approach which ditches the package      
    // NOTE! This will require all your resource bundles to be uniquely named!
    int lastPeriod = bundleName.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (lastPeriod != -1) {
        bundleName = bundleName.substring(lastPeriod + 1);
    }
    InputStreamReader reader = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {

        File file = new File("C:\\temp\\mybundles", bundleName);

        if (file.isFile()) { // Also checks for existance
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            reader = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(reader);
        }
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fis);
    }
    return bundle;
}
```

}

Note also that this supports UTF-8, which I believe isn't supported by default otherwise.

Comment: Supporting UTF-8 breaks for .properties files that contain non-ASCII ISO-8859-1 characters (codepoints 128-255), which is legal. ISO-8859-1 represent these with one byte each, while UTF-8 uses two bytes for them.

Comment: This comment is incorrect. UTF-8 has a variable number of bytes and is the right answer for internationization - which is the point of using ResourceBundles. See this related question and associated accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229156/how-many-characters-can-utf-8-encode

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me very well. And it doesn't reload the bundle everytime. I tried to take some stats to load and reload the bundle from external file location.

```
File file = new File("C:\\temp");
URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myResource", Locale.getDefault(), loader);
```

where "c:\temp" is the external folder (NOT on the classpath) holding the property files, and "myResource" relates to myResource.properties, myResource_fr_FR.properties, etc.

**Note:** If you have the same bundle name on your classpath then it will be picked up by default using this constructor of URLClassLoader.

Credit to http://www.coderanch.com/t/432762/java/java/absolute-path-bundle-file

Find some of the stats below, all time in ms.
I am not worried about the initial load time as that could be something with my workspace or code that I am trying to figure out but what I am trying to show is the reload took way lesser telling me its coming from memory.

Here some of the stats:

- Initial Locale_1 load took 3486
- Reload Locale_1 took 24
- Reload Locale_1 took 23
- Reload Locale_1 took 22
- Reload Locale_1 took 15
- Initial Locale_2 load took 870
- Reload Locale_2 took 22
- Reload Locale_2 took 18
- Initial Locale_3 load took 2298
- Reload Locale_3 took 8
- Reload Locale_3 took 4

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use the resourceboundle class to load the properties - just to get it done in one line instead of 5 lines code through stream, Properties class and load().

FYI ....

```
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
    super.init(servletConfig);

    try {

            /*** Type1 */
        Properties props = new Properties();

        String fileName = getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/classes/com/test/my.properties");
    //          stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    //          stream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/class/com/test/my.properties");  

        InputStream stream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/com/test/my.properties");

  //        props.load(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        props.load(stream);

        stream.close();
        Iterator keyIterator = props.keySet().iterator();
        while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) keyIterator.next();
                String value = (String) props.getProperty(key);
                System.out.println("key:" + key + " value: " + value);
        }

  /*** Type2:  */
  // Just get it done in one line by rb instead of 5 lines to load the properties
  // WEB-INF/classes/com/test/my.properties file            
  //            ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.test.my", Locale.ENGLISH, getClass().getClassLoader());
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.ibm.multitool.customerlogs.ui.nl.redirect");
        Enumeration<String> keys = rb.getKeys();
        while(keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = keys.nextElement();
            System.out.println(key + " - " + rb.getObject(key));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ServletException("Error loading config.", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ServletException("Error loading config.", e);
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want the file's **parent** to be on the classpath, not the actual file itself.

Try this (may need some tweaking):

```
String path = "c:/temp/mybundle.txt";
java.io.File fl = new java.io.File(path);

try {
   resourceURL = fl.getParentFile().toURL();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();                     
}               

URLClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(new java.net.URL[]{resourceURL});
java.util.ResourceBundle bundle = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("mybundle.txt", 
                java.util.Locale.getDefault(), urlLoader );
```

Answer (score 0):

The file name should have .properties extension and the base directory should be in classpath. Otherwise it can also be in a jar which is in classpath
Relative to the directory in classpath the resource bundle can be specified with / or . separator. "." is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to load message files for different languages, just use the 
shared.loader= 
of catalina.properties...
for more info, visit http://theswarmintelligence.blogspot.com/2012/08/use-resource-bundle-messages-files-out.html

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
File f = new File("some.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    props.load(fis);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();                    
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (fis != null) {
        try {
            fis.close();
            fis = null;
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class One {

    private static One one = null;

    Map<String, String> configParameter = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, String>());

    private One() {
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("System", Locale.getDefault());

        Enumeration en = rb.getKeys();
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) en.nextElement();
            String value = rb.getString(key);
            configParameter.put(key, value);

        }
    }

    public static One getInstance() {
        if (one == null) {
            one= new One();
        }

        return one;

    }

    public Map<String, String> getParameter() {

        return configParameter;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = One.getInstance().getParameter().get("subin");
        System.out.println(string);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("service"); //service.properties
System.out.println(rb.getString("server.dns")); //server.dns=http://....
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about your answer?