# How to load resource bundle messages from DB in Java?

Tags: java, resources, internationalization, bundle, resourcebundle

Can I load a resource bundle dynamically?  Can I edit a resource bundle dynamically?

It would be best if I can have such a logical resource bundle (i.e. located in context not as physical file).

#### Related:

[How to load a resource bundle from a file resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172424/how-to-load-a-resource-bundle-from-a-file-resource)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you be able to override the [ListResourceBundle](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListResourceBundle.html)?  It provides an extension point for adding in your own `Object[][]` of resource key pairs.

From the javadoc:

```
public class MyResources extends ListResourceBundle {
     protected Object[][] getContents() {
         return new Object[][] = {
         // LOCALIZE THIS
             {"s1", "The disk \"{1}\" contains {0}."},  // MessageFormat pattern
             {"s2", "1"},                               // location of {0} in pattern
             {"s3", "My Disk"},                         // sample disk name
             {"s4", "no files"},                        // first ChoiceFormat choice
             {"s5", "one file"},                        // second ChoiceFormat choice
             {"s6", "{0,number} files"},                // third ChoiceFormat choice
             {"s7", "3 Mar 96"},                        // sample date
             {"s8", new Dimension(1,5)}                 // real object, not just string
         // END OF MATERIAL TO LOCALIZE
         };
     }
 }
```

This example returns a hard coded listing but you can modify that to return whatever you want from a database or anything else.