# Reusing key values in Properties file by overriding ResourceBundle

Tags: java, jsf-2, resourcebundle

Can we reuse the key values in Properties files something like below?

```
key1=hello
key2=#{key1} world!
```

thanks,

---

**Update:** Below is the code to override the ResourceBundle that turns key values reusable,

```
public class Messages extends ResourceBundle {

    public Messages() {
       setParent(getBundle("resources.test", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale()));
           }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
         return parent.getKeys();
    }


    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {

        try {
               return replaceKey(parent, key, 3);
        } catch (Exception e) {        }
    try { return parent.getObject(key);
    } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        return key;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return key;
    }
}
    private Pattern Pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([\\w\\.\\-]+)\\}");

    private String replaceKey(ResourceBundle bundle, String key, int iteration) {
    String message = bundle.getString(key);
    if (message != null) {
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      Matcher matcher = Pattern.matcher(message);
      while (matcher.find() && iteration > 0) {
        // the magic
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replaceKey(bundle, matcher.group(1), iteration - 1));
      }
      matcher.appendTail(sb);
      return sb.toString();
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Please see below for refrence

[Basic Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451215/jsf-how-to-remove-the-surrounding-if-message-not-found-in-messagebundle/6452047#6452047)

[Manuplation](https://code.google.com/p/reflectiveresourcebundle/source/browse/trunk/net/brockmatt/util/ResourceBundleUtil.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's only possible with a custom [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) wherein you override the [`handleGetObject()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#handleGetObject%28java.lang.String%29) method to check if the retrieved bundle value doesn't contain some specific syntax which should be substituted with another bundle value accordingly.

Finally just register the custom `ResourceBundle` instead in the `<resource-bundle>` or `<f:loadBundle>`.

Comment: You can find a kickoff example in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451215/jsf-how-to-remove-the-surrounding-if-message-not-found-in-messagebundle/6452047#6452047