# Specifying other Path to ResourceBundle / i18n for Vaadin

Tags: plugins, mvp, vaadin

**Is it possible to specify another path than the classpath for the properties files of [Vaadin MVP plugin](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/mvp-and-uibinder-for-vaadin)?**

My main objective is to try to decouple these properties files at e.g. live deployment of the product being developed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin uses `ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, locale)` internally in the `ResourceBundleUiMessageSource` class. This means that it only looks at the class path and you cannot specify arbitrary locations externally.

However, all source code is included with the plugin, so you can extend it to use `PropertyResourceBundle`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172424/how-to-load-a-resource-bundle-from-a-file-resource-in-java) for more details.