# Loading resource bundle outside WEB-INF/classes folder

Tags: java, resourcebundle

For some reason the messages.properties file is located somewhere in `WEB-INF` folder but outside `WEB-INF/classes` folder. Specifically the file's path is /WEB-INF/messages/messages.properties. How do I load this resource bundle using the method `ResourceBundle.getBundle( ? )`?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172424/how-to-load-a-resource-bundle-from-a-file-resource-in-java

Comment: since only classes folder is in classpath, only possible way I see is to override Tomcat class loader some way. Easy way is to put messages folder in classes dir .

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path using the Servlet context as follows;

```
getServletContext().getResource("/messages/messages.properties).getPath();
```

then using the URLClassLoader() create a class loader and pass this on to the getBundle() method.

Answer (score 0):

I just put together a ResourceBundle.Control extension that handles this exact situation:

https://gist.github.com/Tzrlk/82d74c074e63955a8a35

usage:

```
ServletContext servletContext = //! get access to servlet context instance
Locale locale = //! get access to locale instance

try {
    ResourceBundle.Control control = new ServletContextBundleControl(servletContext);
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/WEB-INF/messages/messages", locale, control);
} catch (MissingResourceException error) {
    // handle exception 
}
```