# Where to include .property file in jboss 7

Tags: java, jboss7.x, properties-file

I have a property file which is being called as a resource bundle from one java class and this java classes are wrapped as one JAR file and being included in another java application. From the second java application, I need to call this property file. While doing that, I am getting exception

```
"Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name DSPDB, locale en_US"
```

I am not sure where to include that `.property` file so that it is visible at runtime.

Please help.

Comment: could you post the structure of your jar file? Where is the prop file right now?

Comment: do you mean `.properties`? Normally, it should be stored in `src/main/resources`. Once you package you JAR, it will be moved inside that JAR in correct place (normally, root directory)

Comment: Hi @Valijion, is it not possible to place the .property file outside the jar file?I am deploying this jar in jboss 7. I want to place it somewhere on the server so that it is easy to configure.

Comment: Yes you can. You need to implement this code: `System.getProperty("some_key", null);` to check where some_key is defined by environment or execution parameter. So, later, you can execute: `java -jar your_jar.jar -Dsome_key=path/to/properties`

Comment: can you elaborate this? I have already tried placing the property file in the configuration folder of the server and tried loading it. But it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Please find the code modified: private final static String BUNDLE_NAME = "DSPDB";

 private final static ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle
   .getBundle(System.getProperty(DSP_PROPERTIES_HOME) + File.separator
     + BUNDLE_NAME);

Comment: @Valijon can you elaborate this? I have already tried placing the property file in the configuration folder of the server and tried loading it. But it doesnt seem to be working. Please find the code modified: private final static String BUNDLE_NAME = "DSPDB"; private final static ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle .getBundle(System.getProperty(DSP_PROPERTIES_HOME) + File.separator + BUNDLE_NAME);

Comment: Try to get you path from `System.getProperty(key, default)` and implement by this recommendation [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1172467/3710490](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1172467/3710490)

Comment: I have still not resolved this. can any help?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following link thought it will be helpful:

https://developer.jboss.org/message/615618

Basic idea is to put the property file in a config path and make the path available on class path of JBOSS server.